# Get active objects from list

Tags: java, random

Lets say we have:

```
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

where `Item` is my custom class, which can have two states (boolean) active (true) or not active (false) it has boolean `isActive()` which returns current state.

Now what I am trying to do, is to receive random item from the list `(from 0 to items.size() - 1)` but it has to be active.

What I was thinking to do is to after getting random item from the list, check if its active, and if not, repeat till we receive active item, if its active, return it so we can use it.

Not sure if its right approach, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the right approach.  Do you have some code to share?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem I have with your suggested approach is that it can become very inefficient under certain conditions, particularly when you have very few active `Item`s in your list. Another idea would be to create a new list containing the indexes of all of the active `Item`s in the `items` list:

```
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>(items.size());

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    if (items.get(i).isActive())
        indexes.add(i);
```

Then you simply need a random element from `indexes`, and would refer to the `Item` in `items` at that particular location. So your random active element would be

```
items.get(indexes.get((int)(Math.random() * indexes.size())))
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the ratio between active and inactive items.
If most items are expected to be active, then go with your idea, otherwise you can go woth A.R.S' solution.

**Note:**

There is a caveat with the retry approach. If all items are inactive you will end up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would give you more control by iterating through the list and collecting all active Items into a new list.

```
private List<Item> activeItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

foreach (Item x in items)
{
    if (x.Isactive) activeItems.Add(x);  
}
```

Once you've got the list of only active items, get a random position from that list.

Comment: Although I like ARS's solution better, as the List<Integer> he's creating most likely has a lower memory overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `ArrayList` and create a method that returns a new `ArrayList` (or other `Collection` maybe) only with active items.

class MyItemArrayList extends ArrayList {

public ArrayList getActiveItems() {

```
ArrayList<Item> activeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Item item : this) {

    if (item.isActive()) {
        activeArrayList.add(item);
    }
}



   return activeArrayList;


 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
    List<CustomClass> list = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();


    Random random = new Random();


    while (true) {
        int nextInt = random.nextInt();
        if (nextInt > 0 && nextInt <= list.size()) {
            if(list.get(nextInt).isActive()){
                // Current state is active
                System.out.println("Found active");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```